# How to show list & thumbnail widget in plupload?

Tags: files

I have installed the following modules:

[FileField Sources Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources_plupload), [FileField Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources), [Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) module and added latest plupload library.

While uploading multiple files it is showing only list of files but its not showing the widget for thumbnail & list view.

So how to show that widget.

Comment: Not clear; what do you mean by "widget for thumbnail & list view"? Are you able to upload the files using Plupload, or Plupload does not show at all?

Answer (score 0):

The [Plupload integration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) does not support the UI components of the [Plupload Library](http://www.plupload.com/). It is just as the module name suggest an integration with the library. The actual preview/thumbnails of uploaded images is handled by other modules like in your case [FileField Sources Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources_plupload) and [FileField Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources). You can check the module maintainers answer [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1884858). For modules that integrate with Plupload scroll down to the list on the module page.